# Sorting a list of files to be uploaded in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, os.walk

My goal is to have python upload files from a set directory to telegram, using telegram-upload, in ascending order. The script that I have cannot seem to upload in order. It uploads the files in random order. I've used the `sorted` function to no avail. Looking at my script you can see some things I've tried (commented). I had a setup with `sorted` that would list the files in order, but when attempting to upload, I couldn't re-convert the list I had created and sorted back to a string so `subprocess` could read the arg.

Here's the script:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
#import shutil

Number_Of_Files = 0
#PATH = r'C:\Users\myuser\Downloads' 
PATH = '/home/pi/Public/'

for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(PATH):
    for item in files:
        #Number_Of_Files=Number_Of_Files+1
        fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
        #sorted = sorted(fileNamePath)
        #subprocess.run(['telegram-upload', '-f', 'my_channel', str(sorted)])
        subprocess.run(['telegram-upload', '-f', 'my_channel', str(fileNamePath)])
        #os.remove(fileNamePath)
        print(fileNamePath)
        #time.sleep(60)
    #else:
        #print(Number_Of_Files)
```

Comment: you are sorting `files`. am I right? if yes, then it will be `for item in sorted(files):`

Comment: Thank you for including commented versions of code that did not work. So many new programmers fail to show what they've tried, and it's very frustrating. I appreciate you not making me guess what the problem is, and instead providing concise but complete information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` does not work in place. The `subFolder` argument *must* be sorted in-place if you want to propagate the changes back to `os.walk`. If you want to use `files` directly, you need to sort that in-place too. Otherwise, you need to use the sorted version:

```
for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(PATH):
    files.sort()  # This sorts in-place
    subFolder.sort() # If you want sorted directories
    for item in files:
        fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
        subprocess.run(['telegram-upload', '-f', 'my_channel', fileNamePath])
```

If you don't want to sort the two lists in-place, you could write it like this instead:

```
for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(PATH):
    subFolder[:] = sorted(subFolder)  # creates a new list and assigns back to the original
    for item in sorted(files):
        fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
        subprocess.run(['telegram-upload', '-f', 'my_channel', fileNamePath])
```

It's pointless to run `sorted` inside your loop. Since `sorted` creates an new list every time, and the loop is over the original `files` list, your call to `sorted` is having no effect. You generally want to apply sorting before looping over a sequence, as I've shown above.

Comment: So, I just wanted to say thank you very much.  I added
```
 files.sort(key=str.lower)  # This sorts in-place
    subFolder.sort() # If you want sorted directories
```
To my code and it worked like a charm.  The only change i had to make was the ```(key.str.lower)``` because it wanted to sort the A & a separately.  Funny, I was beating all round the bush, but never saw my error.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole loop can be greatly simplified by using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

p=Path('/home/pi/Public/')

for fn in sorted((x for x in p.glob('**/*') if x.is_file())):
    print(fn)
    # subprocess.run(['telegram-upload', '-f', 'my_channel', str(fn)])
```

The `glob('**/*')` is a recursive glob equivalent to using `os.walk` but a little easier to manage. The `(x for x in p.glob('**/*') if x.is_file())` is a comprehension that only returns files, not directories and files. The result of that is sorted and away you go...

Given this folder structure:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── b.txt
│   ├── d.txt
│   └── y.doc
└── B
    ├── a.txt
    ├── c.txt
    └── x.doc
```

`sorted((x for x in p.glob('**/*') if x.is_file())` returns files in this order:

```
./A/b.txt
./A/d.txt
./A/y.doc
./B/a.txt
./B/c.txt
./B/x.doc
```

If you change the sorted comprehension to `sorted((x for x in p.glob('**/*') if x.is_file()), key=lambda x: x.name)` then you would sort that same tree only by filename:

```
./B/a.txt
./A/b.txt
./B/c.txt
./A/d.txt
./B/x.doc
./A/y.doc
```

Or sort by suffix first then name with `sorted((x for x in p.glob('**/*') if x.is_file()), key=lambda x: (x.suffix, x.name))`:

```
./B/x.doc
./A/y.doc
./B/a.txt
./A/b.txt
./B/c.txt
./A/d.txt
```

With the same method, you can sort by time created, directory name, extension, whatever...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I used @Mad Physicist fix and it worked like a charm.  However, I plan to make use of your suggestion in another iteration of the program.  I didn't have much luck with glob before, but you have inspired me to try again.

Comment: Well seen shortcut.