# Specific timing of a subprocess yields undesireable results

Tags: python, time, subprocess

My goal is to have this script run on a remote computer and at a 'specific' time, execute the subprocess (one time) every hour.  The script runs as expected until the it's time to run the subprocess.  Instead of executing one file at a time, it runs all the files without stopping.  I also tried using various sleep times to break the cycle, to no avail.
Here is the script:

```
import time
import os
import subprocess

print("Waiting To Upload File ... ")
PATH = r'C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample'
while True:
    r = time.localtime()
    m = r.tm_min
    s = r.tm_sec
    if m == 43 and s == 0: #I want to run the script below at this specific min/sec.
        for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(PATH):
            files.sort(key=str.lower)
            subFolder.sort()
            for item in files:
                fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
                print("Uploading: " + fileNamePath)
                print("This is where my subprocess would be")
                #os.remove(fileNamePath)
                print("Upload Successful, " + time.asctime())
                time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Current m/s", m, ':', s, "\r", end="")
        time.sleep(1)
```

And here is my output:

```
Waiting To Upload File ... 
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\CustomLoadSheet.pdf
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful, Sun Feb 21 11:43:00 2021
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\Default.aspx.pdf
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful, Sun Feb 21 11:43:01 2021
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\DeliveryDetail(2).pdf
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful, Sun Feb 21 11:43:02 2021
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\DeliveryDetail.pdf
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful, Sun Feb 21 11:43:03 2021
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\ESP8266ModuleV1.pdf
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful, Sun Feb 21 11:43:04 2021
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\track.pdf
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful, Sun Feb 21 11:43:05 2021
Current m/s 43 : 19
```

I've used multiple configurations, but I'm still stuck. The original ([Sorting a list of files to be uploaded in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095316/sorting-a-list-of-files-to-be-uploaded-in-order)) version of the script worked perfectly, but using `time.sleep()` caused the time the subprocess was executed to slowly move around the clock.  I'm trying to have it run one file at a time, at the same time, every time.

Comment: you should use an OS-level tool like `cron` or Window's Task Scheduler for something like this

Comment: This looks perfect. It starts at 11:43 as requested and then removes all the files in the loop. Are you saying you want to remove one (different) file per hour?

Comment: @PaulH Well, I meant to mention that I'm intentionally trying to not use those tools ... if i can help it.  Trying to stay with a self contained python script.  I've had hit and miss success with the reliability of  ```cron```.  Seems no matter what I do, it doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @AlexHall yes.  the subprocess is an uploader tool.  I would like to have it upload once per hour, advancing to the next file in the list as sorted.

Comment: if you want to only upload a single file each hour, it seems like you shouldn't walk through the whole tree. Instead pop the first item out of the list

Comment: I'd recommend to take the current time and compute a sleeptime till the desired time, because this is quite inefficient. There is also a tiny chance you miss the X:43:00 time: if the program happen to check 1 millisecond to soon (X:42:59.999), than waits 1 whole second + 2 ms some overhead, next check will be 1 ms too late (X:43:01.001) and the hourly run is missed. If you reduce the sleep below 1 second, it will be even more inefficent.

Comment: @PaulH, you're right, I shouldn't have to walk the whole directory, but if not, a random file will get selected.  It's the only way I've found to keep them in order.  Pre-sorting the directory on the OS side has no effect.

Comment: @VPfB, Sounds interesting.  can you point me to an example of this time calculation method you describe?

Comment: @TrcyPrkr I think you'll have better luck with `pathlib.Path(...).glob()` than `os.walk` in terms of preserving order

Comment: `cron` isn't the recommended tool on modern Linuxy systems regardless -- see systemd timers (or, if you want to trigger whenever a directory's content changes, path units; they're built explicitly for the purpose). There are Windows-centric tools for watching directories for changing as well; there's never a good reason to go the poll-every-N-minutes/seconds approach when you can instead have the OS inform you immediately whenever a file is created/changed/closed/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, here is an example of a sleeptime calculation for a task repeated hourly at given minute and second.

```
import datetime as dt

def get_sleeptime(minute, second):
    """Return seconds from now till nearest *:min:sec time"""
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    sched = now.replace(minute=minute, second=second, microsecond=0)
    sleeptime = (sched - now).total_seconds() # the difference is a timedelta object
    if sleeptime < 0:
        sleeptime += 3600
    return sleeptime
    
print(get_sleeptime(43,0) # test
```

I thnik its usage in the main loop is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The package `apscheduler` basically gives you `cron` within a python script.  Here is an example with your script that runs the scheduled task at 43 min after the hour:

```
import apscheduler
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time
import subprocess
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def make_generator_func_callable(gen_func):
    # a decorator that makes generators callable so they can be used with scheduler
    task_generator = gen_func()
    def callable_generator():
        try:
            return next(task_generator)
        except StopIteration:
            print("(nothing left to do)")
    return callable_generator


@make_generator_func_callable
def my_task(path=PATH):

    for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(path):
        files.sort(key=str.lower)
        subFolder.sort()
        for item in files:
            fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
            print("Uploading: " + fileNamePath)
            print("This is where my subprocess would be")
            #os.remove(fileNamePath)
            print("Upload Successful, " + time.asctime())
            #time.sleep(1)
            yield


@make_generator_func_callable
def test_task():
    for item in [1,2,3]:
        print(datetime.now())
        print(item)
        yield


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Waiting To Upload File ... ")
    # start scheduler as a background/non-blocking process
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()

    # your cron-style task. This is also an "interval" option
    # scheduler.add_job(my_task, "cron", minute="43", id='my_job')
    scheduler.add_job(test_task, "interval", seconds=3, id='test_job')

    # this is a blocking prompt to prevent your script from exiting
    ans = input("press return to shutdown the script")
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Why use a dedicated scheduler package?  Scheduling tasks is not entirely trivial, and benefits greatly from a dedicated background process. If you try to "roll your own", you may run into any of the following issues:

- jobs accidentally submitted multiple times because they complete quickly
- jobs missed/skipped because your process was busy doing something else at desired time
- jobs fail and prevent your code from continuing

By contrast, `apscheduler` handles all these difficulties for you and has more advanced features when you need them (job persistence across sessions, etc)

Note the revised script converts your script into a generator function (which is then wrapped to make callable).  This may not be the most elegant solution but will get the job done with minimal modification

Comment: Ok.  I really like this idea.  But,  this method still cycles through all the files in the directory at once.  Somewhere after the ```for item in files``` loop, there needs to be a way to break the loop once one file has been processed, until the next hour.

Comment: So, i added ```break``` after ```time.sleep``` in the function and it worked in the shell.  Now I'll go live and see what I break.

Comment: I think I see what you want now.   I can update later today

Comment: do you expect the list of files to remain static across time?

Comment: After each file is successfully uploaded, it will be deleted.  But, I would like the sort to remain. ie, run down the list of files in alphabetical order, upload, delete.

Comment: By the way, my adding ```break``` in the function actually breaks it.  Apparently, the subprocess i'm using sends file chunks by looping itself, so 'breaking' that loop, breaks the uploader.  The subprocess i'm using is [telegram-upload](https://docs.nekmo.org/telegram-upload/usage.html#telegram-upload)

Comment: alright, I've updated the solution.  If you run it as-is, it will run a test function which just prints to console every three seconds.  You can just uncomment the other job to do the task you desire.

Comment: One key bit is using `yield` - this is what you're were trying to achieve with break.  Every time it's called, it basically pauses at `yield` (could also return a value), and then resumes the next time it's called until it hits `yield` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229064/discussion-between-trcyprkr-and-anon01).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, after studying and testing all of the suggestions and answers, the most recent answer by @VPfB was the easiest to integrate into my existing script.  I just wanted to post it here for others who wish to use it or do something similar.  The only addition I had to make was to place a 1 second sleep at the end, but before the `get_sleeptime` call to break the loop long enough for the timer to take over.  So far it runs perfectly.  Here is the final product ...

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import os
import subprocess

PATH = '/home/pi/Public/'
def get_sleeptime(minute, second):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    sched = now.replace(minute=minute, second=second)
    sleeptime = (sched - now).total_seconds() # the difference is a timedelta object
    if sleeptime < 0:
        sleeptime += 3600
    return sleeptime

for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(PATH):
    files.sort(key=str.lower)
    subFolder.sort()
    for item in files:
        fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
        print("Uploading: " + fileNamePath)
        print("")
        subprocess.run(['telegram-upload', '-d', '-f', 'file_dumpster', str(fileNamePath)])
        print("")
        print("Upload Successful >> " + time.asctime())
        print("")
        time.sleep(1) #added to break loop long just long enough
        print(" <<... Waiting To Upload New File ...>> ")
        time.sleep(get_sleeptime(11, 0)) #set at 11 minutes past the hour
```

And here is the output ...

```
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\New Text Document - Copy (2).txt
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful >> Mon Feb 22 19:10:26 2021  #initial file upload
 <<... Waiting To Upload New File ...>> 
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\New Text Document - Copy (3).txt
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful >> Mon Feb 22 19:11:00 2021  #11 minutes past the hour
 <<... Waiting To Upload New File ...>> 
Uploading: C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample\New Text Document - Copy (4).txt
This is where my subprocess would be
Upload Successful >> Mon Feb 22 20:11:00 2021  #11 minutes past the hour
 <<... Waiting To Upload New File ...>>
```

Answer (score -1):

As @VpFB suggested, you try and calculate the waiting time:

```
import time
import os
import subprocess
import datetime

def get_next(minute, second):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    next_time_args = dict(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day,
                          hour=now.hour+1, minute=minute, second=second)
    return datetime.datetime(**next_time_args)

def wait_till_next(next_time):
    now = datetime.datetime()
    seconds = (next_time-now).microseconds / 1e6  # 1e6microsecond=1s
    if seconds>0:
        time.sleep(seconds)



print("Waiting To Upload File ... ")
PATH = r'C:\Users\trcyp\Documents\PythonExample'
next_time = None
waited = False  # this makes sure you upload the next hour's file even if your previous upload took more more than an hour but less than two hours.
while True:
    r = time.localtime()
    m = r.tm_min
    s = r.tm_sec
    next_time = get_next(minute=43, second=0)
    if waited or (m == 43 and s == 0): #I want to run the script below at this specific min/sec.
        for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(PATH):
            files.sort(key=str.lower)
            subFolder.sort()
            for item in files:
                fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
                print("Uploading: " + fileNamePath)
                print("This is where my subprocess would be")
                #os.remove(fileNamePath)
                print("Upload Successful, " + time.asctime())
                time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Current m/s", m, ':', s, "\r", end="")
        wait_till_next(next_time)
        waited = True
```

Comment: it's bad practice to use reserved keywords (e.g. `next`)

Comment: this is not valid python: `now = datetime.datetime()`

Comment: perhaps your `get_next` is more succinctly written with `datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`

Comment: Hi @anon01 thanks for your remarks! I've edited my answer.

Comment: Your first two comments are perfectly valid, I've missed them. The last one is not, because we don't want the scheduler to go "around the clock". datetime.timedelta(hours=1) would result in adding the latency of now.